# input stream in C++. A little confusion with cin unget() function

Tags: c++, cin

Could anybody clear a little confusion I have about `cin.unget()` function. 
Please consider this piece of code:

```cpp
void skip_to_int()
{
    if (cin.fail()) {                   // we found something that wasn’t an integer
        cin.clear();                    // we’d like to look at the characters
        for (char ch; cin>>ch; ) {      // throw away non-digits
            if (isdigit(ch) || ch=="-") {
                     cin.unget();       // put the digit back,
                                        // so that we can read the number
                     return;
            }
        }
    }
    error("no input");                  // eof or bad: give up
}
```

if `cin.unget()` put the digit back into input stream to be read again, wouldn't I get `cin>>ch` the same character to check conditions for again, and therefore get stuck in infinite loop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lets take a closer look at `skip_to_int`

```
 if (cin.fail()) {
```

if the last input was bad

```
       cin.clear();
```

clear the flags and look for the next good data

```
       for (char ch; cin>>ch; ) {
```

get a character

```
            if (isdigit(ch) || ch=="-") {
```

if character is a character we want

```
                 cin.unget();
```

put it back into the stream

```
                 return;
```

***exit the function!!!***

```
            }
```

otherwise loop back around to get the next character

```
        }
```

no more characters, exit the loop

```
  }

  error("no input");
```

Immediately following the `unget`, the function returns, ending the loop along with the function.